# how to apply facebook type loader in reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

[This class fetches data from URL and displays result using Axios.](https://github.com/boy108zon/react-component-bootstrap-ajax/blob/master/src/users_box.js)
[Facebook style.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-content-loader)

How can I apply Facebook type style in class `UsersBox` for Title, Address, Tagline etc?

Comment: my view is similar to this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/boxes-with-icon-hover.,

Comment: Is it resolved ? Because i have a long answer to type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Tried but not getting it.

Comment: sorry Rodrigo , i don't want to write code for me , i only need suggession or logic of it.